# PHPUnit run a dynamically generated list of tests

Tags: php, phpunit

We are currently running PHPUnit tests with a suite. Is it possible to run a list of tests which are dynamically generated?

Use case: I just want to pull up all the latest failed tests (that I have in a DB) and run them at once to verify that they pass before I fix a common issue for all the failed tests.

Comment: This will be supported out-of-the-box in PHPUnit 7.3.

Comment: @SebastianBergmann Can you explain this a little bit?

Comment: See https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/3147

Comment: @SebastianBergmann Thank you. My use case is a little different. 

I do not want all the failed tests to get picked up. I am only interested in certain type of failures and have those tests run. I was thinking about creating a new custom phpunit.xml file with these tests under a suite and provide this config file(which would reside in some temporary folder) to the PHPUnit framework. Is this possible or is there a better way to do this?